# How can I run a dask-distributed local cluster from the command line?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I would like to do the equivalent of `Client(LocalCluster())` from the command line.

When interacting with distributed from Jupyter notebooks, I end up restarting my kernel often and starting a new `LocalCluster` each time, as well as refreshing my bokeh webpage.

I would much rather have a process running in the background that I could just connect to, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant doc page here is http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html#using-the-command-line

In one terminal, write the following:

```
$ dask-scheduler
```

In another terminal, write the following:

```
$ dask-worker localhost:8786
```

The defaults are a bit different here.  LocalCluster creates N single-threaded workers while dask-worker starts one N-threaded worker.  You can change these defaults with the following keywords

```
$ dask-worker localhost:8786 --nthreads 1 --nprocs 4
```